# Why does my push notification keep repeating irregularly?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

A push notification set up using alarm manager and pending intent is displaying unusual behavior. For some reason, the notification comes up a minute or less after I open up the app. Sometimes more than once a minute, then it doesn't show up for a while. My idea is to have the notification be given off once a day, assuming the user hasn't access my app in over 24hrs. I intend to cancel any previous timer, and start a new one for 1 day when the user next accesses my app. Below is my code.

```
public class Main_Menu extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);


    Button goToGame1;

    goToGame1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Game1);
    goToGame1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent beAtGame1 = new Intent(Main_Menu.this, memory_modes.class);
            startActivity(beAtGame1);
        }
    });


Button goToGame2;

    goToGame2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Game2);
    goToGame2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent beAtGame2 = new Intent(Main_Menu.this, computation_modes.class);
            startActivity(beAtGame2);
        }
    });


Button goToGame3;

    goToGame3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Game3);
    goToGame3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent beAtGame3 = new Intent(Main_Menu.this, evaluation_modes.class);
            startActivity(beAtGame3);
        }
    });


    Button goToGame4;

    goToGame4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Game4);
    goToGame4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent beAtGame4 = new Intent(Main_Menu.this, attention_modes.class);
            startActivity(beAtGame4);
        }
    });


    Button goToTrackers;

    goToTrackers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Trackers);
    goToTrackers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent beAtTrackers = new Intent(Main_Menu.this,trackerMenu.class);
            startActivity(beAtTrackers);
        }
    });



    Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Menu.this, Receiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main_Menu.this, 1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarm.setRepeating(alarm.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), alarm.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);


    }

public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

and

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    showNotification(context);
}

public void showNotification(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main_Menu.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smalliconfinal)
            .setColor(Color.argb(000,255,177,17))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon4))
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Some text.");
    mBuilder.setLights(0xffffb111, 750, 750);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}

}
```

and from my Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver"></receiver>
```

Anyone know why this issue occurs?

Much appreciated,
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to the [AlarmManager.setRepeating](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method is the time the alarm should first go off.

You're calling this method using these parameters:

```
alarm.setRepeating(alarm.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), alarm.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Which means that you're setting the repeating alarm to go off as soon as you call the method (when the `Main_Menu` activity is created).

From your description it seems like you're looking for something like this:

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Much appreciated.